# PyQGIS calculate the actual map dimensions on a dynamic layout

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, print-composer, pyqgis-3, atlas

I'm writing a plugin to more easily create atlas coverage rectangles, which are to scale and can dynamically rotate from portrait to landscape orientation. I've also written in some code which can read a .qpt file and extract for instance the map layout items, and lets the user pick which one should be used to draw the to-scale rectangles.

There is one small issue I have with this: The .qpt file only saves the map dimensions in the orientation it was last saved in, however the layout also has a dynamic legend, which stays on the bottom of the entire page. This means that the map dimensions and aspect ratio change based on if its currently in landscape or portrait.

[image: Example of what I'm talking about with how rotating the map wouldn't really work]

So I'm having a bit of trouble with the math on how I should approach this. Currently in my plugin, I just have it generate the rectangle once, and whenever I want to rotate it, it just uses a simple:

`self.rectangle.rotate(self.rubberBand_angle, point)`

However this wouldn't work when using this dynamic layout as shown above. The aspect ratio's just arent the same.
I also want to make sure that the rectangle isn't just the full page, as this could lead to accidentally covering important information with the legend.
In the layout I've also got these expressions to determine the map size:
Width = `@layout_pagewidth - (@layout_margin*2)`
Height = `@layout_pageheight - @layout_legend_height  - @layout_margin*2`

And my layout also has some expressions for the page size: 
Width = `if("Rotation" is 0,420,297)`
Height = `if("Rotation" is 0,297,420)`
(Rotation is a field inside of the atlas features created by the plugin so the layout knows it should rotate the page as well).
My preference would be to calculate the map size first, and then not have to deal with the rotating it right before I create the rectangle feature. But I honestly don't know where I should start to calculate that. Does anyone maybe have some insight on this?

Sorry for not including a lot of the code, 1 because its pretty bodgy and probably way to big, and 2 because there are still some hardcoded variables in there would could contain slightly sensitive information.

Comment: Is the legend always the same size? (That is to say, is the rotated map always going to cover the same proportion of the page?). And how does the user choose which orientation to use, is it by selecting a shape, or clicking a button, something else?

Comment: @Matt The legend height always stays the same, but like I tried to illustrate in the picture, the proportion of the space the legend takes up isn't the same based on which orientation the page would be in. The rotation is just a checkbox the user presses in the plugin. If they want landscape they uncheck the box, if they want portrait the check the box. This could of course also be something else. I just found that for me a checkbox works the fastest. The user gets to select a paper size, or a custom .qpt file. Scale and rotation

Comment: Apologies if I miss something, but it is not clear to me why your expressions are unsuitable. Subtracting the height of the legend from the height of the page gives you the available space, does it not? It seems calculating the map size, before the page size is determined, is not possible.

Comment: Ah yes my apologies. I'm trying to calculate the size of the rectangle feature which should be created to perfectly make a layout map to a certain scale. For instance for an A3 map on 1:1000 scale the rectangle should be X map units wide and Y map units high.